# Database not Updating 1000

Tags: sql, vb.net, database-connection

Hi heres the code it has no errors but when you check the database nothing is added

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Create_btn.Click
    Call getConnect()

    If New_Username.Text = "" And New_Password.Text = "" And New_Pass_Code.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("check the empty textbox or wrong Admin Password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "needed")

    Else
        con.Open()

        sql = "INSERT into Accounts (Username, Password, Pass_Code) values('" _
                                              & New_Username.Text & "','" _
                                             & New_Password.Text & "' , '" _
                                             & New_Pass_Code.Text & "')"

            Dim sqlcomd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        sqlcomd.CommandText = sql
        sqlcomd.Connection = con
        sql = sqlcomd.ExecuteNonQuery


            MsgBox("data saved")
        con.Close()

    End If
```

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, please google paramaterized queries. You'll find it easier to write queries and your code won't be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: change `sql = sqlcomd.ExecuteNonQuery` with `sqlcomd.ExecuteNonQuery` ...

Answer (score 0):

try to check your connection string. the data might be saving to another database.